# Application Server CPU is Always hogging at 50%

Tags: multithreading, apache, jboss, load

After a load test in my application, my application server CPU is hogging at 50% always even though nothing is running in the system after the test. When I look at the thread dump, I can see at least 24 BLOCKED threads in the dump. Most of them are related to spring framework, mule framework and so on....nothing specific to my application.

[image]

Please see below for a few stack traces of the thread dump.

```
"ajp-10.40.44.47-8009-116" daemon prio=6 tid=0x000000000cdce800 nid=0x7ac waiting for monitor entry [0x000000003cf1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:291)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000c274dab8> (a org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.WebCtxLoader$ENCLoader)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:340)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:437)
    at org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor.createEndpointURIBuilder(DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor.java:448)
    at org.mule.endpoint.MuleEndpointURI.initialise(MuleEndpointURI.java:222)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet.getReceiverForURI(MuleReceiverServlet.java:308)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet.doAllMethods(MuleReceiverServlet.java:241)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet.doPost(MuleReceiverServlet.java:198)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.mule.transport.servlet.MuleReceiverServlet.service(MuleReceiverServlet.java:180)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)

"financials.pctogl.staging.partitioned.jms.taskExecutor-9" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009b8f000 nid=0x1730 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002cf1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"[powercomp].iip.flow.drools.service.stage1.01" prio=6 tid=0x00000000063af800 nid=0x1608 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002979f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

"task-scheduler-10" prio=6 tid=0x000000000d075000 nid=0xcf0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000002649f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler.handleError(MessagePublishingErrorHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:59)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

"UDP ucast,10.40.44.47:61710" prio=6 tid=0x0000000009b82800 nid=0xeb0 waiting for monitor entry [0x000000001771e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:201)
    - waiting to lock <0x00000000a197e360> (a org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jProxy.log(Log4jProxy.java:301)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4jProxy.error(Log4jProxy.java:283)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:208)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.down(TP.java:1205)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$ProtocolAdapter.down(TP.java:2316)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.down(Discovery.java:374)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.down(MERGE2.java:175)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.down(FD_SOCK.java:362)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.sendHeartbeatResponse(FD.java:325)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD.up(FD.java:235)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:309)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.up(MERGE2.java:144)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:264)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.PING.up(PING.java:273)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$ProtocolAdapter.up(TP.java:2327)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1261)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.access$100(TP.java:49)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.handleMyMessage(TP.java:1838)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$IncomingPacket.run(TP.java:1817)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1746)
    at org.jgroups.util.ShutdownRejectedExecutionHandler.rejectedExecution(ShutdownRejectedExecutionHandler.java:39)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:767)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:658)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.dispatchToThreadPool(TP.java:1366)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.receive(TP.java:1333)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP$UcastReceiver.run(UDP.java:960)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You have a question?  If you have a problem with CPU waste, (and it does seem like you have:), why are you bothered by the blocked threads anyway - they are blocked. If your system is idle, all threads should be blocked - it's the ones that are running that are generating the CPU load.

Comment: Yes, I have a question. What  thread is causing my CPU to be always at 50% even though nothing was running in the application. I have just thought BLOCKED threads are the cause. I may have overlooked. How to find out those threads in the thread dump and what can we do about them.

Comment: Have you tried using visualvm, or any other basic performance analysis tool for Java? With the information you provided, it's pretty much impossible to even start thinking about what might possibly be wrong :-)

Comment: The even load on the machine and the fact that you have blocked threads probably means that your threads are in a kind of a livelock - all doing some work but not really progressing.Analyse the reason for the BLOCKED threads - that is the cause and even if it does not consume all your resources yet it will sooner or later if you do not address the issue.